# Generate mongodb schema without data for a new project installation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a project in nodejs with a mongodb database and i would like to create a brand new deployment of the project for another customer so i need the same database structure without old data.
What should i do?
Do i have to create all collections manually or there's a way to script just the database schema?

**EDIT**

I have been told that mongoose will automatically create the collection if it doesn't exist when the connection to the database is opened

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using the MVC model.

I will share on of my model file with you to understand how you can write a re-usable database schema code.

```
const expenseCollection = require('../db').db().collection("expenses");
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const Money = require('./Money')

let Expense= function(data, userId){
    this.data = data,
    this.authorId = new ObjectID(userId)
    this.errors =[]
    }

//MAZZA BELOW ARE THE FIELDS MENTIONED THAT YOU MAY WANT TO HAVE IN YOUR SCHEMA
Expense.prototype.cleanUp = function(){
    this.data ={
        amount: Number(this.data.amountSpent),
        item: this.data.item,
        purchaseDate: new Date(this.data.purchaseDate),
        notes: this.data.notes,
        status: false,
        expType: this.data.expType,
        authorId : this.authorId,

    }
}
```

module.exports = Expense

Also, I will share with you how can you pass the data in this constructor.
(From one of the of the controller file)

```
const moneyController = require('./moneyController')
const Expense = require('../models/Expense')

exports.saveExpense = async function(req, res){
   
        let data = {
        balance:0,
        }
        let money = new Money(data)
    await  money.addMoney(req.session.user_id)
await money.subtractBal(req.body.amountSpent, req.session.user._id )

//MAZZA FOCUS ON THE BELOW LINE:
    let expense = new Expense(req.body, req.session.user._id)



await expense.saveExpense()
res.redirect('/')

}
```

Primarily, the model will be a file, wherein you can write the reusable schema script.

Consider making separate model for each collection, that is 1 collection = 1 new model in your code.

Also, in the above code that I shared with you, it will automatically create the collection even if it does not already exist in the mongodb.